# Creating an entity attribute to one of multiple Entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, structure

So I have the following entity called `Link`, which has the following attributes:

```
id
source
target
type
```

where source and target each can link to one of the following entities: `Project` or `Task`. But this is not possible, since a attribute can only refer to one entity.

How do I go about this problem? Do I have to create an entity for each type, e.g

- LinkProjectTask
- LinkTaskProject
- LinkProjectProject
- LinkTaskTask

This seems like a mess and indicates a not thought out application structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `Project` and `Task` represented by a class?
You could have a base class that both of these entities inherit from and use that to define your `Link` class, documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

example:

```
class Base
{

}

class Project extends Base
{

}

class Task extends Base 
{
}

class Link
{
   private $source;
   private $target;

    public function getSource(): Base{
        return $this->source;
    }

    public function setSource(Base $source): void {
        $this->source= $source;
    }

    public function getTarget(): Base{
        return $this->target;
    }

    public function setTarget(Base $target): void {
        $this->target= $target;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, this really helps. I will see how I can implement this, but I think this is the way to go. Thanks!